# Cloudant Java client not create index

Tags: java, cloudant

I'm using

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.cloudant</groupId>
            <artifactId>cloudant-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I call the function createIndex
where

```
db = dbManager.getDatabase();
        List<Index> indexes = db.listIndices();
        String indexName = String.format("index_%s", getModelClass().getSimpleName());
        if (indexes != null && !indexes.stream().filter(c -> c.getName().equals(indexName)).findFirst().isPresent()) {
            Log.debug("Creating index for " + indexName);
            db.createIndex(indexName, indexName, null,
                    getIndexFields() != null ? getIndexFields().toArray(new IndexField[0]) : null);
        }
```

I obtain the log:

```
Created Index: '{"name":"index_AccountOwner","ddoc":"index_AccountOwner","index":{"fields":[{"collectionName":"asc"},{"conversationId":"asc"}]}}'
```

But in the db on cloudant there aren't a JSON called `index_AccountOwner` that define the index.

OPTIONAL: without the index fields I can't use sort in the query right?

Comment: Did you print out the value of `indexName` to verify that it contains what you expect?

Comment: Yes, indexName is index_AccountOwner